# Can I set number of rows in table by the value of a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way to change size of a table (created through <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), by typing the number of rows in some cell? If the table has formulas they should be copied to new rows too.

For example I have a table at A1:B10 (10 rows), now I type "20" in D1 (some random cell), the table now should become 20 rows large (A1:B20).

Also I'd like to be able to set range for a diagram in the same manner.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take a few minutes to read [ask], then update your question with details about what you have tried. We will try to help you from there.

Comment: Question needs clarification. A spreadsheet in Excel is already a table that essentially goes on forever. What is it that makes it look like a table of a particular size to you? What do you want to put in the populated cells?

Comment: I'm talking about insert->table(ctrl+t) kind of table. A table created this way has a control that allows to change its size in tle right bottom corner, new cells should be filled in the same way.